# Even though $A^kx=0$ for some positive integer $k\geq 2$, $Ax=0$ may not be satisfied.

Tags: linear-algebra

Write True or False and why?

Q1 : Even though $A^kx=0$ for some positive integer $k\geq2$, $Ax=0$ may not be satisfied.

Q2 : Suppose that the columns of matrix $A$ are linearly independent. Then $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Assuming you mean $A^{k}x$, this is a true statement since, for instance, there are matrixes whose n-th power is null, yet they are not null in the first place. Consider for instance $$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{array} \right)$$

Clearly for any x with a non-zero element in the first coordinate, $Ax\neq 0$, yet $A^{2}x=0$ for all $x$ since $A^{2}=0$ (you can check this).

Q2: This is because if the columns are independent, the linear system $Ax=0$ has one unique solution, and since the trivial solution $x=(0,\dots,0)$ always satisfies the equation, then no other solution exists.

You can reason this by seeing that the determinant is non-zero, for instance. In fact, if there were a non-trivial solution, writing it explicitly would imply the existence of $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$ such that $$\lambda_{1}A_{1}+\dots\lambda_{n}A_{n}=0$$ (where $A_{i}$ is the i-th row of the matrix) with nonzero $\lambda_{i}$'s, hence denying linear independence.